# Logistic Regression gradually tends to predict all 0s while training on mini batches

Tags: regression, classification, binary-data, nlp

I am using mini-batches to train my model which is as follows

```
SimpleModel(
  (embed): Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, max_norm=2)
  (model): Sequential(
    (0): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
    (1): Linear(in_features=in_features, out_features=1, bias=True)
  )
  (sig): Sigmoid()
)
```

these are the specifics of the model and upon training through mini-batches, after 2-3 minibatches all the outputs become `0.` training function looks like this while the training loop is usual

```py
def trainer(train_loader, model, optimizer, criterion):
    model.train()
    it_loss = 0
    counter = 0
    for data in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        msgs = data['msg']
        targets = data['target']
        out = model(msgs)
        print(out)
        loss = criterion(out, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        it_loss+=loss.item()*msgs.shape[0]
        counter+=msgs.shape[0]
        
    return it_loss/counter
```

I have tried using various optimizer and all those things, data is not imbalanced as shown

```
0    3900
1    1896
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

what could be the possible reason and how can I solve it

Edit :

The output of first mini batch looks like

```
tensor([[0.4578],
        [0.4569],
        [0.4686],
            .
            .
            .
        [0.4602],
        [0.4674],
        [0.4398]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)
```

while output of 4th or 5th mini batch looks like

```
tensor([[0.0057],
        [0.0058],
        [0.0058],
            .
            .
            .
        [0.0058],
        [0.0057],
        [0.0059]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)
```

And furthermore it gradually becomes exact `0.`

Comment: What loss are you using? If there is low signal, then [accuracy rewards outputting only the majority class](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).

Comment: @StephanKolassa I am using binary cross entropy with logits, I have tried using cross entropy loss as well but there's no effect

Comment: OK, then that should not be it. I don't know whether we can help you any more than this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/352036/1352

Comment: @StephanKolassa I am facing this weird error only while using pytorch, while using tensorflow things went smooth

Comment: How do you figure the data are not imbalanced? Category $0$ sure looks to have twice as many members as category $1$.

Comment: @Dave I mean surely its not 50-50 but its not that much of a great imbalance, category 1 is one third of the entire dataset

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Changed the optimizer and Loss function**

Used the [`RAdam`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.RAdam.html) optimizer and changed loss function to [`BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html) and it worked

Comment: Just so that future readers are aware of *why* this works, BCELoss with a sigmoid activation is the same as BCEWithLogitsLoss and no separate sigmoid activation because BCEWithLogitsLoss includes the sigmoid activation within it. However, round-tripping exp and log when using sigmoid + BCELoss can cause a loss of precision, so your model may blow up when it computes `log(0)`. BCEWithLogitsLoss combines these operations and doesn't round-trip, so it's more numerically stable.

Answer (score 1):

## Remove the sigmoid activation.

The loss function [`BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) assumes that the input is a **logit**. You're passing *probabilities*, not logits.

> This loss combines a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss in one single class.

Comment: what activation should I use then? and even when I use cross entropy loss the result is same

Comment: As the first sentence of the documentation says, the loss function combines the sigmoid activation and the loss computation into a single function. You don't need any activation at all with this loss function; it's already included.